# Different shells on SSH and local

Tags: 14.04, bash, ssh

So I've got an Ubuntu 14.04.2 computer that has OpenSSH Server installed on it. Whenever I use the computer locally, through the terminal, if I run:

```
~$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

However, if I SSH into the machine through PuTTY, and run the same command, it returns:

```
/bin/sh
```

I've checked `/etc/passwd`, and it's set for `/bin/bash` on my account, and when I run `chsh`, it's also set for `/bin/bash`. I would like to use the bash shell by default over SSH. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you verify the default shell setting for your account on the *remote* machine? Also, the SSH server configuration may enforce some other shell. What's the content of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`?

Comment: Does `PuTTY` "help" you with some initialization commands?

Comment: `sshd_config` doesn't seem to have anything with it, and I couldn't seem to find anything in the man page about forcing a shell at login.

I also couldn't find anything in the PuTTY documentation about it either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
ssh -t username@host "/usr/bin/bash"
```

The `-t` is necessary, to create a pseudo-tty for the shell to use as an interactive shell.

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119899/107084)

Comment: @marranaga Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). ;)